# bitmap size exceeds VM budget when images are loading from base64 content

Tags: android, image, bitmap, base64

I am getting images from my back end in base 64 format, decoding it and loading the images in a grid view. It works fine for the first time but when I click the "show more images" button it gives me the error **bitmap size exceeds VM budget**. When i click on that button I get images in base64 format and I set the adapter of the grid view again in order to refresh the view. I read many of the answers related to this problem but all of them are reading images from drawables and not receiving in base64 format. My code to get the images decoded from base64 to bitmap is as follows:

```
public static void getImages(JSONObject jobj){
    try{
        JSONArray jarr = jobj.getJSONArray("images");
        Log.v("array size",""+jarr.length());
        for(int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); i++){
            String encodedContent = jarr.get(i).toString();
            byte[] decodedContent = Base64.decode(encodedContent);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedContent, 0, decodedContent.length);
            images.add(bmp); //Static array list to save the bitmap images
        }
    }catch(JSONException e){
        e.getMessage();
    }
```

Next time the images come in after clicking the "show more images" button it gets added to that images arraylist. Can anyone help me on suggesting how can I remove this error I am getting?

Comment: scale down the bitmap

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks for the advice but how do I get to know the ideal size to scale down the image to so that it works in all the android devices? I might sound stupid asking this but I am quite a noob at working with images in android.

Answer (score 1):

You could have the base64 coded string be saved into a file first, and then use that file reference everywhere else.

That would be more reliable in terms for the sizes of Bitmaps, and after you save it to a file, scaling down, as mentioned in the comment by Raghunandan is also easily possible.

Comment: I am loading almost 8 images at a time from my back end. And having that data written to a file for each image and then again scaling down the image would increase the overhead of showing the images. I am hoping there is some better solution to this?

Comment: You are right that it would take some time, but in most of the cases, writing 8 files in one go would probably take a second or two. And after that, you have the advantage of re-using the files, if you want.

Comment: So you are suggesting that if I have loaded 16 images I should have created 16 files containing their base64 format content? Coz if I put all the contents in the same file then again I will have to parse it for different images. Right?

Comment: Yes. Separate files for separate images